# how to send multiple files from local data (different folders) laravel

Tags: laravel, file, email

how to send selected files from the checkbox ,, files have 2 files in 1 folder ,,
then attach it to the email at laravel

**View**

```
<label for="basic_checkbox_{{$i}}"></label>
   <input type="hidden" id="id_cus" name="id_cus[]" value="{{$data->id_cus}}" />
  <input type="hidden" id="ic" name="ic[]" value="{{$data->id_cus}}" />
```

[UI send data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19O1Y.png)

**Controller**

```
 Mail::send('adminpage.message.template_reply',["data"=>"Report Assessment"], function($message) use($excel)
        {
            $message->from('optikserasi.ind@gmail.com', 'Global');

            $message->to('wakudiallah05@gmail.com')->subject('Assessment');

            $message->attach($excel->store("xls",false,true)['full']);

        });
```

[folder file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgpv0.png)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I can't retrieve files on the local but on the DB I have

Answer (score 0):

@ialx see Doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#attachments

Attach file from local

```
foreach($paths as $path) {
   $message->attach($path);
}
```

Attach Raw Data (in your case from DB)

```
foreach($models as $model) {
   $message->attachData($model->rawData, 'name.pdf', [
                    'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                ]);
}
```